# Change TPL file based on taxonomy term

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to change the tpl.php file used depending on the taxonomy term applied to a node.

There is a snippet on [this page](http://drupal.org/node/415400) that explains how to do that. However, it is written for Drupal 6, and doesn't work for Drupal 7.

The snippet is as follows:

```
// Add this to your theme's template.php
// Replace "THEMENAME" with your theme's name
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-term-'. $term->tid;
  }
}
```

I have tried to update it for Drupal 7 as follows:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
    $variables['template_files'][] = 'node-term-'. $term->tid;
  }
}
```

However, it still doesn't work. I just get the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$taxonomy in
>   THEMENAME_preprocess_node()  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in THEMENAME_preprocess_node()

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably handle it with the following code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->field_myfield[$variables['node']->language][0]['tid'])) {
    $tid = $variables['node']->field_myfield[$variables['node']->language][0]['tid'];
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__term_'. $tid;
  }
}
```

Now if a term with the id 6 would be referenced from a node's 'field_myfield' Drupal would look for a template named 'node--term_6.tpl.php' and use that if available.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) you can find everything you need to know about template suggestion in D7.

I think in your case, the template should look like `page--taxonomy--term--1.tpl.php`. No need for preprocess functions.

Comment: Thanks! But page--taxonomy--term--1.tpl.php changes the page.tpl.php file. I want to change the node.tpl.php file. How can I do that (The page you linked to doesn't explain it).

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node-term-'. $term->tid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks! That code produces an error message. (It's the same error message as listed in my opening post).   Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: you should var_dump the `$variables['node']` and see the exact structure of the variable. I think in D7 the node structure is changed regarding the taxonomy. Locate the taxonomy related part in `$variables['node']` and make the necessary adjustments

Comment: How do I do that? Also what would I look for to make the necessary adjustments?

Comment: put this before `foreach(...` and tell me what it'll show up: `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($variables['node'], true) . '</pre>');`