# How to send HTML email

Tags: 7, emails

I am creating a simple module which will be sending HTML emails to users for deals in our website.

I have searched a lot, but I can't find a solution proper solution for Drupal. Now I can send mails but plain text.

What is a step-by-step procedure to send HTML emails in Drupal 7?

```
function example_form_submit( $form,&$form_state) {
    $friend_email=$form_state['values']['friend_email'];
    $mailto =$friend_email;  //gift to a friend
    $mailfrom ='no-reply@example.com';
    $subject = "another message for  HTML email from example.com";
    $body="<h2 style='font-size:28px;color:red;'>Hello EMAIL, i here i want to be <b>bolded</b></h2>";
    if (drupal_mail('example', 'send_gift', $mailto, language_default(),$params,$mailfrom,TRUE)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your gift was sent successfully!!!'));
    }
    else {
        drupal_set_message(t('<font color="red">Error occured while sending your mail!!!</font>'));
    }


/****hook_mail*/
function example_mail($key,&$message,$params) {
    $language = $message['language'];
    switch ($key) {
        case 'send_gift':
            $message['subject']=t($params['subject'], $var, $language->language);
            $message['body'][]=$params['body'];
            $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing Full HTML page

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like geoff mentioned one option would be to use the Mime Mail module, but you can also enable your custom module to send HTML e-mails with some extra code. In short you'd need to alter the `mail_system` variable and write your own implementation of `MailSystemInterface`. An example of that is the following code.

Inside 'mymodule.install':

```
function mymodule_enable() {
  $current = variable_get('mail_system', array('default-system' => 'DefaultMailSystem'));
  $addition = array('mymodule' => 'MymoduleMailSystem');
  variable_set('mail_system', array_merge($current, $addition));
}

function mymodule_disable() {
  $mail_system = variable_get('mail_system', array('default-system' => 'DefaultMailSystem'));
  unset($mail_system['mymodule']);
  variable_set('mail_system', $mail_system);
}
```

Inside 'mymodule.module':

```
class MymoduleMailSystem extends DefaultMailSystem {
  public function format(array $message) {
    $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
    $message['body'] = drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
    return $message;
  }
}
```

You'd have to replace mymodule instances with your actual module's name then disable and re-enable your module to get the variable changed after which things should be working. For a complete example you can check out my answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23821/email-a-whole-node-including-template-contents). Additionally [this](http://drupal.org/node/900794) page on drupal.org is from where I originally got all the information from.

Comment: i followed your instructions + the complete example you gave now everything is working... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

[Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module is almost certainly what you are looking for.

> This is a Mime Mail component module (for use by other modules).
>
> - It permits users to receive HTML email and can be used by other modules. The mail functionality accepts an HTML message body, mime-endcodes it and sends it.
> - If the HTML has embedded graphics, these graphics are MIME-encoded and included as a message attachment.
> - Adopts your site's style by automatically including your theme's stylesheet files in a themeable HTML message format
> - If the recipient's preference is available and they prefer plaintext, the HTML will be converted to plain text and sent as-is. Otherwise, the email will be sent in themeable HTML with a plaintext alternative.
> - Allows you to theme messages with a specific mailkey.
> - Converts CSS styles into inline style attributes.
> - Provides simple system actions and Rules actions to send HTML email with embedded images and attachments.

Comment: i have downloaded the mimemail module+mail system... will you be kind to please explain to call the mimemail function to my module as the code above.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me, so here is my take on the original question.

First of all, install and enable the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module. You can read the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mimemail/tree/README.txt) for complete instructions on how to use it. I'll give you the short version.

You need to enable Mime Mail for your module. You can do this using `hook_enable` or `hook_update_N` in `example.install`:

```
function example_enable() {
  mailsystem_set(array(
    'example_send_gift' => 'MimeMailSystem',
  ));
}
```

When you go to `admin/config/system/mailsystem` you will see that a new entry has been added for your module:

> Example module (send_gift key) class
>
> MimeMailSystem

Now you don't need to specificy any `text/html` headers anymore, Mime Mail takes care of this. So you don't need this:

```
$message['headers']['Content-Type'] = ...
```

If you want, you can add `$message['plaintext']` to your mail for a non-HTML alternative, but this is not required.

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at the Swift Mailer module. It lets you send HTML e-mails with both inline and regular attachments (such as images or files). Furthermore, it is also capable of automatically generating plain text versions based on the HTML e-mail.

You can have a look at it http://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer

For the record: I'm the author and maintainer of the module.

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending proper HTML , you are only including H1 tags and B tags, you probably need to include Full HTML tags as well starting from 
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: thx for ur comment,i used @Dooshta example,also added the proper html as u suggested.. everything is working.

Comment: I'm sure there is no harm in using a doctype & fully validating HTML, but it is not required to send an HTML email through drupal. I just removed the doctype & html tag and the email rendered well in Gmail & Outlook. *However*, it is very important to have Dooshta's fix in place: before I implemented those changes I was not able to generate any html at all.